# how can I force ssh to open a connection from a specific port to an host?

Tags: ssh, openssh

i would like to create an SSH connection from my pc to another but I want to start the connection from a specific port number that is decided by myself.

is it possible? how to?

thank you

Comment: Do you need to have specific local endpoint's port? What language do you need it in?

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to use a specific port on the server, or a specific port on the client?

Comment: 2 host: A and B. A wants to connect to B. I would like that the connection on A will be on a specific port, like 4444 or anything else it doesn't matter but i have to know that number a priori so i have to force to open the connection on that port. So, A connect to B, source port 4444 to destination port 22.

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'ephemeral port'.  I'm also trying to figure out how to force outbound ssh connections to go on an ephemeral port that I pick, while keeping the inbound port as 22.  Reason being I can use an iptables filter to allow multiple applications to listen on 22 (e.g. http), and route traffic according to the outbound port instead of the inbound one.

Answer (score -2):

You must configure the SSH server to use another port than 22.

It could be done for example in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in most Linux distribs.

Comment: no. like this i can modify the port number which i connect to. Instead i wanna change the port at the source host not at the destination

Comment: Source ports are dynamically assigned by OS. I don't think there is an easy way to manually assign a port client side. `lsof -i` tells me that my ssh connections are using ports 50000+...

Comment: exactly, i would like that that port will be assigned by myself and not by the OS.